# PHP UserId changes to the UserId of the last user that logged in (changes user)

Tags: php, authentication, session-variables

**So what is happening is a little bit weird and I have no clue what is causing it.**

After some minutes after I login into my account on my website and I refresh the page it changes to the last user that logged in so I have full access to that user account just by refreshing it, because it changes to that user.

So if I'm logged in with ***User1*** account and I refresh after some minutes I end up on ***User2*** account and have full access to the account just like I had logged in into that account.
I think it's something to do with the Session but I have no clue what it is.

**I have this on the beggining of pretty much every page:**

```
    <?php
        set_time_limit(0);
        session_start();
        include_once("includes/global.php");
        db_connection();

        if (!is_login())
        {
        header("location: login");
        }
        else
        {
    ?>
```

**And here it is the function that checks the login:**

```
    function is_login()
{

    if (isset($_SESSION['userId']) && ($_SESSION['username']) && ($_SESSION['regDate']))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        @session_destroy();
        return false;
    }

}
```

*If you need any more code let me know, because I have no clue what is the problem so don't know what code to show.*

Comment: Can you reproduce this reliably?

Comment: Check the cookies, if the session ID changes.

Comment: As a test, you could add `print_r($_SESSION)` to one of the pages and record the output for both cases. Check the difference between them and see if all the information really is changing. Looking at the cookies is a good idea as well.

Comment: @cyberbit I printed the Userid after I refreshed the page and it got me to another user and the userid also changed to that new user account. I can't really give the information after it's changing because it didn't changed yet again, just after sometime, but this is the Session I have right now Array
(
    [userId] => 1
    [username] => Evolutiounx
    [regDate] => 2015-10-07 00:00:00
    [userType] => 1
    [cards_val] => 0
    [pagepage] => cart
    [dumps_val] => 0
    [extratime] => 5
)

Comment: @gre_gor Yes it changes to the same Userid as the account that it changes to

Comment: Do a search in all your files for the `$_SESSION['userId']` variable. Are you sure you're not manipulating it in some way?

Comment: @Terminus Already did, it's not manipulating userId in anyway

Comment: Do you use `session_id` anywhere?

Comment: @DavideGonçalves did you any solution to this?

Comment: You are saying that your account is replaced by last user logged into. Is last used logged out or not. If he already logged out, can you also share me logout code.